# _printf is being printed twice

Tags: assembly, att

I am attempting to use the `_printf` function, and everything works OK except for one thing: it prints the result twice. The issue is that I am not receiving any errors other than the unexpected behavior. I attempted to add a null terminated character but was unable to change the result. However, that should not be an issue since if I am not incorrect, the string should be defaulted to make the string null terminated.

I am compiling the code with:

```
as --32 ./bin/assembly.asm -o ./bin/a.o
ld -m i386pe ./bin/a.o -o ./bin/a -lmsvcrt
```

The assembly code:

```
.section .text
    .global _start
_start:
    call main
    movl %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
.section .data
LC0:
    .string "hello\0"
.section .text
main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    sub $0, %esp
    pushl $LC0
    call _printf
    add $4, %esp
    movl $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

The output:

```
hellohello
```

I have tried to reinstall the `msvcrt.dll` but that did not help, have also tried to restart the computer, have also tried to use `puts` and `putchar` but with the same result.

Comment: What do you think happens after the final instruction of `_start` is reached?

Comment: Since you are asking, I would assume that it keeps on reading the code, which results in main being run twice? However, I am unsure of it works like that. I tried adding a `leave` and `ret` but that resulted in a `segfault`

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.  Try calling the `_exit` function to end the process.

Comment: I feel stupid. Thank you, that worked.

Comment: Single stepping with a debugger is a good way to catch "stupid" / obvious mistakes before telling other humans about them. :P  Every has brain farts, debuggers reduce the amount of farting in public.  In this case you'd see execution fall through into `main` again after it returned.  Not exactly a duplicate of [What if there is no return statement in a CALLed block of code in assembly programs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41205054) since `_start` isn't called by anything else.  But I think close enough.

Comment: I'm surprised the CPU didn't try to read the `.data` section as code and crash. But then again, the assembler is probably smart enough to put `data` before `text` no matter where it is in your document.