# How does CALL in Assembly work? Does it return again to execute the further instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, callstack, function-call

```
start:
    mov $0, %eax
    jmp two

one:
    mov $0x1234, %eax

two:
    cmp $0x1234, %eax
    je done
    call one
    mov $10, %eax

done:
    jmp done
```

I have a doubt that when `cmp` in `two` is called for the first time, it won't match, so it will go to previous instruction again when `call one` is called. But after that when it again comes to `two`, and `je done` is executed, will it directly go to `done` or will `mov $10, %eax` will also be executed?

I tried looking up the working of both `jmp` and `call`. I understood it, but can't really apply it.

Comment: Call pushes a return address and jumps.  If nothing ever pops that return address back into the program counter (e.g. with a `ret` instruction while the stack pointer is pointing to it), it doesn't return.  There is no magic.  You can single-step it yourself in a debugger.  Near duplicate of [What if there is no return statement in a CALLed block of code in assembly programs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41205054) which has similar code.  Actually the code is basically identical in control-flow, and my answer there does answer your question.

Comment: (BTW, this is AT&T syntax, like for GCC or clang, not [masm].  I fixed the tag for you.)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the previous instruction"?

Comment: The flow of control, i.e. sequence of instructions to execute, is very well defined.  Each and every instruction informs the processor of the exact next instruction to execute.  For example, when `call` runs, it pushes a very specific return address on the stack, so when `ret` executes it resumes execution in the caller at that same exact address.  Jumps and branches also have very specific operations that inform the CPU what to do in terms of what to do next.  So, if you want to understand control flow, look into each specific instruction to see what it does, then one after another.